# How do I get updates on my questions?

Tags: support, notifications

Is there a way or an extension that I can install to get notifications on my asked questions? And does Stack Overflow have an application that I can install on my Android device to get updates on the go?

Comment: See http://stackapps.com for a list of desktop and mobile phone applications to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install any separate application to get updates for your posts like question or answers.

You will gets update like notification of any edit made in your posts. If someone write comments on your posts you will get that notification as red circle in the left top corner and you can see it in your inbox.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I so what happens then?

Comment: re your other comment about jave me tag, your warm words are much appreciated, thanks. I plan to get back after a while. Currently, [cleaning up link-only answers at Programmers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10101975#10101975) takes a bit too much effort, I expect this cumbersome "janitorial duty" to be completed in about 2-3 months - after that, I hope to get back to nurture [my favorite tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-me)

Comment: @user2585335, what do you mean by "then" ?

Comment: Thanks Disregard that please. Thank you i would be expecting your response to my other question thank you.